# What attempts have been done to prove the continuum hypothesis?

Tags: set-theory

Of course CH is independent of ZFC but at least Cantor himself tried to prove it. So which attempts has been done in this direction? Are they any trials that are not completely wrong?

Edit:
I'm interested in results/techniques that have arisen from attempting to prove the CH as Theo said in his comment.I am not interested in wrong proofs of freshmen but in wrong proofs of, for example, Cantor himself.

Comment: The Continuum hypothesis is neither true nor false. There are models in which it is false. Hence, the continuum hypothesis CANNOT be proven. Cantor didn't know this result, his efforts were doomed to fail which we today know.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but "not completely wrong" is a difficult thing to quantify. The most sensible interpretation of this question I can think of is that you're asking what kind of interesting results/techniques have arisen from attempting to prove the CH.

Comment: What do you mean "not completely wrong"?

Comment: You are aware that Cantor tried to prove $\mathrm{CH}$ only because he couldn't possibly know that it would be independent of $\mathrm{ZFC}$, right? At this point, I'm not sure if you are asking a legitimate question (extending $\mathrm{ZFC}$ is a natural way to settle $\mathrm{CH}$) or maybe if you are confused about the concept of independence. You might want to add to your question to clarify what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: Again, I know what indpendance means. I know that Cantor didn't know it. I'm interested in results/techniques that have arisen from attempting to prove the CH as Theo said. I am not interested in wrong proofs or freshmen but in wrong proofs of Cantor himself.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think this is the right question to ask, except for purely historical reasons. More interesting is to see modern attempts to "prove" (or "disprove") $\mathsf{CH}$ (which, of course, take into account the fact that $\mathsf{CH}$ is independent of the standard axioms).

Comment: In any case, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/272028/6085) for Hilbert's attempt.

Comment: Hilbert "proved" it? This is more then I had wished for. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your last question is meaningless, given the fact that you *know* that $\sf CH$ can be neither proved nor disproved from $\sf ZFC$.

Cantor's original approach was ultimately through what is now known as the *perfect set property*. This essentially means that an uncountable subset of $\Bbb R$ has a copy of the Cantor set sitting inside of it. And of course, if an uncountable set of reals has the perfect set property, then it has to have the same cardinality as the continuum.

Therefore, the line of thinking goes, if every set of reals is has the perfect set property, then the continuum hypothesis must be true.

Cantor showed how to prove that every closed set of real numbers has a perfect subset. And the proof later pushed through the Borel sets, and can even stretch to continuous images of Borel sets, also known as analytic sets. But that's it. No more than that can be proved without additional hypotheses which are themselves not provable from $\sf ZFC$.

This is demonstrated by the existence of *Bernstein sets*, sets which are uncountable, and while they intersect every perfect set, they contain none. These are sets which definitely do not have the perfect set property. Using the axiom of choice, one can prove that Bernstein sets always exist, and thus came to a close *that* chapter.

Interestingly enough, it was later proved that it is consistent to have the perfect set property hold for every set of reals, and the axiom of choice of course fails. This was done by Solovay and later improved upon by Truss (the improvement was weakening the choice hypotheses and thus omitting the large cardinal hypotheses). This shows that the line of thinking about the perfect set property is consistent, and therefore not entirely flawed.

Comment: That's exactly what I was loking for. Thanks!

Comment: The usual terminology is that a pointclass has the perfect set property if and only if each of its members is countable or contains a perfect subset. I would suggest slightly editing the answer accordingly. (Certainly saying that if a set has the perfect set property then it contains a perfect subset is not the standard usage.)

Comment: @Andrés: I'm not sure everybody knows what a pointclass is. Also, I feel that this is somehow like saying that a set is measurable, or meager, etc.

Comment: The important bit is not the use for pointclasses vs individual sets, but rather that the perfect set property is the dichotomy, not just the uncountable part of it.

Comment: @Andrés: Ah, right. Is things better now?

Comment: Yes, things is now better. :-)